# Given the sequence $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$ with $a_1=2$ and $a_{n+1} = \frac{n^2-1}{a_n} + 2$ for $n \ge 1$, find the following limits.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have the sequence $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$, such that:

$$a_1 = 2, \hspace{1.5cm} a_{n+1} = \dfrac{n^2-1}{a_n}+2 \hspace{.25cm}, \forall n \ge 1$$

And I have to find $2$ limits:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{a_n}{n} \hspace{3.5cm} \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}a_k^3}{n^4}$$

The second one completly put me in the dark. I don't see any trick that I could use.

For the first one, I tried using Stolz-Cesaro:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{n+1-n} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (a_{n+1}-a_n) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \bigg ( \dfrac{n^2-1}{a_n} - a_n \bigg )$$

And I got stuck. I don't think I can find a closed form for $a_n$, so I really don't know what should I do to find these $2$ limits.

Comment: Can you show by induction that $n\lt a_n\lt n+1$?

Comment: The second limit can be obtained from first by Stolz Cezaro

Comment: @J.W.Tanner **If** I can, what then?

Comment: then $\dfrac{a_n}{n}$ is [sandwich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem)ed between $1$ and $1+\frac1n,$ which helps you find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_n}n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy proof by induction that $n\le a_n\le n+1$ with inductive step$$k\le a_k\le k+1\implies k+1=\frac{k^2-1}{k+1}+2\le a_{k+1}\le\frac{k^2-1}{k}+2<k+2$$implies the first limit is $1$ and the second is $\frac14$, since $\sum_{k=1}^nk^3=\frac14n^4+o(n^4)$. In particular, $1\le\frac{a_n}{n}\le1+\frac1n$ gets the first limit by the squeeze theorem, while$$\begin{align}\frac14\left(1+\frac1n\right)^2&=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nk^3}{n^4}\le\frac{\sum_{k=1}^na_k^3}{n^4}\le\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n(k+1)^3}{n^4}\\&\le\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k^3}{n^4}=\frac14\left(1+\frac1n\right)^2\left(1+\frac2n\right)^2\end{align}$$gives the second by the squeeze theorem. (Here I've used $\sum_{k=1}^nk^3=\frac13n^2(n+1)^2$.)

Comment: Can you please explain a little further why knowing that $n \le a_n \le n + 1$ implies that the first limit is $1$? If we know that inequality, we know that $a_n$ goes to $\infty$, right? So, why does the limit $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{a_n}{n}$ equal $1$ then? Sorry if I'm annoying, but I also didn't really get the second limit. You seem to have used $k^3$ in the sum, instead of $a_k^3$ and I don't see where you got that $\dfrac{1}{4} n^4$ from. Can you please explain with a little more detail, so I can understand it?

Comment: @user1502 See edit.

Comment: I've found that I can calculate the second limit using Stolz-Cesaro aswell!

Comment: @user1502 Once you've got $a_n$ bounded, yes.